# C - Compare Pointers From Different Allocations?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, avl-tree

I have implemented an AVL tree in C. Only later did I read that pointer comparison is only valid between objects in the same array. In my implementation, I do certain equality tests. For example, to test whether a node is a right child of a parent I might test `node==node->parent->right`. However, the nodes are allocated as needed, not in a contiguous chunk. Is this behavior defined? How would you write this code instead if it is not?

Comment: *t pointer comparison is only valid between objects in the same array* - Where did you read this nonsense?

Comment: @EdHeal I'm guessing what he read was referring to _in_-equality testing, as in comparing indices or something like that.

Comment: It probably refers to less than or greater than comparisons. Maybe you can provide a quote from the place you read that from?

Comment: @EdHeal less-than, greater-than etc. is only valid between pointers to the same array, perhaps that is what he is referring to. Only `==` and `!=` may be used on arbitrary pointers (of compatible type)

Comment: This source would seem to suggest that equality and not equals, as well as the other inequalities, are invalid if the pointers are not of the same array, or the same memory allocation. http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-comparing-two-pointer-variables/

Comment: You can use less than, greater than for any two pointers. Whether it makes any sense is another matter

Comment: @EdHeal it causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @BigEndian that page you linked is garbage, please disregard

Comment: @BigEndian - On the first hand, Ed Heal points make complete sense, on the other hand your source itself says that *All Equality and Inequality Operators can be used with all Pointer types*! And, **don't follow that crap link**.

Comment: `All Equality and Inequality Operators can be used with all Pointer types` this is where your case applies

Comment: @M.M - How is in undefined behavior? Pointers are essentially numbers representing a location in memory

Comment: For equality and inequality, the standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.9) says: _Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the
same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function,
both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer
to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different
array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address
space._  There's no UB in comparing pointers to unrelated objects.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, can you cite the standard (which standard is it?) and put that in an answer? Also, what is UB?

Comment: @BigEndian - UB = undefined behavio  - Standard is cited - ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.9

Comment: It was not cited a couple minutes ago. I need to look at this standard a moment. I think Jonathan should post an answer.

Comment: The verbiage for relational operators (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.8) is longer: _When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they compare equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members
declared earlier in the structure,_ […continued…]

Comment: […continued…] _and pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P. In all other cases, the behavior is undefined._

Comment: That is perfectly sufficient. Clearly there is some bad information out there and going back to the standard clears things up. I am not surprised by any of that text, it's approximately what I would expect. Please post as an answer so I can mark it as such.

Comment: @EdHeal see 6.5.8/5 (Relational operators) ". In all other cases, the behavior is undefined."  (full text is too large to paste in a comment), but the case of pointers to different objects is not one of the defined cases

Comment: In general pointers are not glorified integers, you're mixing up Standard C with a common implementation detail. In the past we had things like *Segmented Architecture* where there is no absolute ordering of pointers, and in general a pointer could be anything

Comment: MM, who is mixing up pointers with glorified integers? Me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For equality and inequality, in the standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) §6.5.9 Equality Operators ¶6 says:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

There's no undefined behaviour in comparing pointers to unrelated objects for equality or inequality.

By contrast, §6.5.8 Relational Operators ¶5 says:

> When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. If two pointers to object types both point to the same object, or both point one past the last element of the same array object, they compare equal. If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, pointers to structure members declared later compare greater than pointers to members declared earlier in the structure, and pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal. If the expression P points to an element of an array object and the expression Q points to the last element of the same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P. In all other cases, the behavior is undefined.

This means that comparing pointers with `>`, `>=`, `<` or `<=` when the pointers are not pointing to the same object (for the definition of 'same object' given in painstaking detail in the quote), the behaviour is undefined.