# Why can we compare character constants?

Tags: c, if-statement, relational-operators

Came across this statement in a C book, `if ((letter >= 'P') && (letter <= 'S'))`

It's trying to check if the letter falls between P and S (including both) and I was quite surprised to see it work.

1. How is it possible to do greater-than/lesser-than type operations on alphabets (character data type)?
2. It is a feature in only C or in other programming languages as well?

Comment: No experience with C but operations are generaly possible if you treat the characters as its ASCII representation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is it possible

To invert the question, why wouldn’t it be? Our alphabet is naturally ordered, and having an ordering between letters is convenient and just makes sense. In the particular case of C, character literal are simply integer numbers, so ordering them naturally works.

On a more technical levels, characters are mapped to integer numbers by some encoding schema, known as a [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Different encodings exist, and which particular encoding is used isn’t defined by the C standard, and isn’t important for comparing characters, as long as it’s consistent. This also means that C does not guarantee that this ordering corresponds to a particular alphabet, or that letters are consecutive.

> It is a feature in only C or in other programming languages as well?

Virtually every modern programming language allows order comparison of character types.

---

**Caveat:** Many languages extend this capability to character *strings*. Such a comparison is called [lexicographical comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). While C also supports this, e.g. via [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), it’s important to note that C does not allow you to compare strings using operators (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`). Unfortunate C will accept your attempt to do so without complaining:

```
char a[] = "hello";
char b[] = "world";
if (a < b) { /* not allowed! */ }
if (strcmp(a, b) < 0) { /* correct way. */ }
```

The first `if` will compile, but it will do the wrong thing: instead of comparing the string contents, it will convert `a` and `b` to pointers and compare the values of the two pointers. And that is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) ([!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34973704/1968)), which means that it’s not valid C, the result is potentially unpredictable, but the compiler will not necessarily tell you that anything is wrong.

Comment: It should be stated the C standard does not require the codes for letters to be consecutive or to match alphabetical order.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Whïch ålphabét? ;-) (added.)

Answer (score 2):

`char`s in C are actually small integers (normally with range `-128..127`). All operators that work on other integers also work on `char`s, this includes `>=` and `<=`.

A character literal like `'P'` is a *numeric code* of the character (normally an ASCII code, but the standard doesn't specify the encoding). In ASCII, codes for letters are consecutive (separately for `A-Z` and `a-z`), so `>=` and `<=` do the right thing.

---

> It is a feature in only C or in other programming languages as well?

At least one language does: C++ is based on C, so it also has this feature.

Answer (score 2):

> "*How is it possible to do greater-than/lesser-than type operations on alphabets (character data type)?*"

Because the *character constants* refer to numeral [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) values of f.e. the ASCII, Unicode or UTF-8 character set and are listed in the alphabetical order of the characters.

Some references:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

> "*It is a feature in only C or in other programming languages as well?*"

If they support numeral character encoding sets, where characters are listed in subsequent alpabetical order, then yes.

Note, that even the C standard does not specify that character values in encoding sets need to be in alphabetical order.

Also note that the syntax to accomplish the same effect of comparing might be completely different in other languages.